# ReWrite Rule for URLS

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have 2000 URLs in the format: -

```
http://www.example.com/home/2015/02/yet-another-page-title-goes-here.html
http://www.example.com/home/2015/01/another-page-title-goes-here.html
http://www.example.com/home/2014/12/page-title-goes-here.html
```

These are OLD URLs from WordPress, when the old site had permalinks enabled doing this for the blog posts.

I want to strip away two parts of these URLS. I want to remove /home/ and I want to remove .html at the end.

This would mean that if someone follows an old link (in Google or elsewhere), they will come to the new URL for that content.

E.g. somebody tries to access the old expired link:

```
http://www.example.com/home/2015/01/another-page-title-goes-here.html
```

Will be redirected to the new link: -

```
http://www.example.com/2015/01/another-page-title-goes-here
```

I've tried editing the htaccess file in WordPress for the last couple days with no joy so far. Redirect rules are new for me.

I've treid something like this, but it doesn;t work

```
RewriteRule ^home/(.+)\.html $
```

And where do I add this code, if it;s correct, in the htaccess file for WordPress with permalinks enabled.

This is the content of my htaccess file by default. w3cache has added something at the top too.

```
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component  application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
# DEFLATE by extension
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any thoughts would be significantly appreciated,

UPDATED HTACCESS FILE WITH CODE SUGGESTED:

```
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
# DEFLATE by extension
AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^home/(.+)\.html $
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^home/(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteRule`s have multiple parameters. In yours, you only specified a URI to match. You should be using the following format:

```
RewriteRule ^home/(.+)\.html$ $1 [R,L]
```

First, we match `home/<everything>.html` and redirect to `<everything`, denoted by `$1`.

If the new rule works for you, you can safely change `R` to `R=301` to make the change permanent - that is to say that search engines and browsers will cache the redirect for a longer period of time. Without it, you're basically saying that the redirect is temporary, and that it should not be cached.

Your `.htaccess` file should look like this now:

```
# BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css text/x-component application/x-javascript application/javascript text/javascript text/x-js text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon application/json
    <IfModule mod_mime.c>
        # DEFLATE by extension
        AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css htm html xml
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END W3TC Browser Cache

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^home/(.+)\.html$ $1 [R,L]
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END Wordpress
```

Comment: I think he shouldn't use the [L] flag, because Wordpress still needs the last index.php substitution to work.

Comment: Indeed, have amended.

Comment: Original answer was right, because [R] is an external redirection, so it should stop processing and send a redirect header to client. My bad, sorry for inducing you on error...

Comment: @Stuart: I've made some edits to my answer. Please give it a try and let me know if it works.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I really appreciate your time spent on this. The re-write rule still isn't working at all. I've been trying similar things for the last few days on and off and it's not working. There might be some WordPress files outside of htaccess complicating matters?? I'll just go with the old 'Redirect 301 old-link new-link' since it seems to work quite well. And I'll try to look into htaccess later when I have more time. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Would you mind sharing the your entire, updated `.htaccess` file in your question so we can have a look? It's not the best thing to have questions on SO with answers that don't seem to work - especially when others encounter a similar issue.

Comment: Sure Mike. I've updated the original question with my htaccess code. This one has been boggling my mind for a while now an I just can't get anything to work! A couple of thoughts from me. Maybe something in the active theme's functions.php file is interfering with this?? Maybe there is something special about '/home/' in WordPress? Maybe something else is going on...

Comment: I've updated my answer again, removing the `/` from `/$1` and `/index.php`. Not sure if that will make a difference, though. Also, you had the rule in there twice, with `RewriteEngine On` twice too. My updated answer contains what your entire file should look like, so you can understand the bigger picture. Also, there won't be anything special about `home` as the rule is the first thing being checked for, *before* WordPress even boots up.

Answer (score 0):

Stealing the answer from @Mike, that I broke and fixed again:

For the permanent change please put this line:

```
RewriteRule ^home/(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

before the line:

```
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] # this line means never redirect index.php
```

It should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^home/(.+)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks Guys. I'm afraid it's not working for me. When I add your code Filipe, nothing happens. I just get a 404 page not found.

Comment: Can you give me and example of what address it redirected you to?

Comment: [R] means an external redirection, so I think you should try using @Mark's original answer [R,L]. My bad... :-(

Comment: A quick reference: http://www.webforgers.net/mod-rewrite/basic-tutorials-lesson-2.php

Comment: Thanks Filipe. It's not working at all for me I'm afraid. There might be something else in WordPress causing problems. I might just go with sticking 2000 of these at the top of the htaccess file. It will take a couple hours, but at least it works. Redirect 301 /home/2009/11/page-title.html http://www.example.com/2009/11/page-title

Comment: @Stuart Did you change the wordpress domain? If I understood well, when you create a redirect from `/home/{path}.html` to `www.newdomain.com/{path}` it works.